# Having trouble deploying heroku app: application fails to bind to $port

Tags: node.js, heroku

I followed the procedures of the instructor , but the page is giving me an error. can someone help me here?

[Hyper Terminal Application Error heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM7xl.png)

Comment: I have provided an answer which should help. Tip for next time: do not add screenshots but just copy-paste the logs and include some info about the application (language, framework, code snippet). Welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The application uses the default port 3000 which won't work on Heroku: the application needs to bind to the port provided in the PORT env variable

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```